# MySQL - Escaping double quotes and brackets when querying JSON column

Tags: mysql, json

how do you escape double quotes and brackets when querying a JSON column containing an array of objects?

This works when I run it...

```
SELECT boarded, boarded->>"$[0].division.id" AS divisionId FROM onboarder
```

But this doesn't...

```
SELECT boarded, boarded->>"$[*].division.id" AS divisionId FROM onboarder
```

I thought double arrows escaped everything and bought back only the value. This is what I have...

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The `->>` operator does not escape anything. It just converts the result to a scalar data type, like `text` or `integer`. It's the equivalent of doing [JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(...))](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-modification-functions.html#function_json-unquote):

> *Unquotes JSON value and returns the result as a utf8mb4 string.*

We can demonstrate the difference between `->` and `->>` by using the result set to create a new table, and inspecting the data types it creates.

```
create table t as SELECT boarded, boarded->"$[*].division.id" AS divisionId FROM onboarder;

show create table t;
CREATE TABLE `t` (
  `boarded` json DEFAULT NULL,
  `divisionId` json DEFAULT NULL
);

select * from t;
+------------------------------------+--------------+
| boarded                            | divisionId   |
+------------------------------------+--------------+
| [{"division": {"id": "8ac7a..."}}] | ["8ac7a..."] |
+------------------------------------+--------------+
```

Note divisionId is a json document, which is an array.

If we use `->>` this is what happens:

```
create table t as SELECT boarded, boarded->>"$[*].division.id" AS divisionId FROM onboarder;

show create table t;

CREATE TABLE `t` (
  `boarded` json DEFAULT NULL,
  `divisionId` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin
)

select * from t;
+------------------------------------+--------------+
| boarded                            | divisionId   |
+------------------------------------+--------------+
| [{"division": {"id": "8ac7a..."}}] | ["8ac7a..."] |
+------------------------------------+--------------+
```

There's no visible difference, because the square brackets are still present. But the latter is stored as a `longtext` data type.

---

Re your comment:

> *How can I return divisionId as a value so that it's not an array and quoted?*

You used `$[*]` in your query, and the meaning of this pattern is to return all elements of the array, as an array. To get a single value, you need to query a single element of the array, as in your first example:

```
boarded->>'$[0].division.id'
```

This would be so much easier if you didn't use JSON, but stored your data in a traditional table, with one division on its own row, and each field of the division in its own column.

```
CREATE TABLE divisions (
  division_id VARCHAR(...) PRIMARY KEY,
  merchant ...
);

CREATE TABLE merchants (
  merchant_id ... PRIMARY KEY,
  division_id VARCHAR(...),
  FOREIGN KEY (division_id) REFERENCES division(division_id)
);
```

The more examples I see of how developers try to use JSON in MySQL, the more I'm convinced it's a bad idea.

Comment: Thank you for that explanation. How can I return divisionId as a value so that it's not an array and quoted?

Comment: @Dally Using `[*]` means you want the value from every element of the array. How would that be returned as a single string rather than an array?

Comment: @Barmar Each row will only have one division. One division has one merchant that can contain several channels. That's my workflow.

Comment: Then you need at least a table for divisions and another table for channels.

Comment: If it can only have one division, why is it an array? Anyway, just use `[0]` to get the one element of the array. Or there can be multiple objects, but only one of them has a `division` property?

Comment: @Dally I think you could use `JSON_EXTRACT(board, "$[*].division.id")->"$[0]"`

Comment: That works, but I don't see how it's any better than the former extract expression which extracted the first element of the array, then the `.division.id` of that element.